# Display a neat set of files in my application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file

I have a set of files written to a temporary directory which I want to display to the user. In this instance I wish them to be able to select a file and then have the option of saving it. Is there a decent control in C# for doing this?

Comment: So basically what you want to do is, 'copy' a specific set of files written to temp directory to another location?

Comment: Kind of, i want to display the files i have written to a temp location to the user in order for them to choose if they actually want them or not, the temp location gets cleaned up after use anyway

Comment: what about file dialog? show dialog user, selects files and you will have list of file. Then you can do with files whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use OpenFileDialog and FolderBrowserDialog for example:

```
using (OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
{
  dialog.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";//your temp directory path
  dialog.Title = "Select files to move/copy";
  if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
  {
     string[] files = dialog.FileNames;
     using (FolderBrowserDialog save = new FolderBrowserDialog())
     {
        save.Description = "Select location to save files";
        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
           foreach (string file in files)
           {
              FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo(file);
              File.Move(file, save.SelectedPath + finfo.Name);
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: ok so i can get all the file names in the files array - how do i then use that to get the user to select a location to save too :/

Comment: Well after selecting files you can show FolderBrowserDialog with description = "Select location where files will be saved". And after selecting folder move files there.

Answer (score 0):

Would a simple [Open File Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.aspx) be sufficent? You can restrict it to only show the files with your temporary extension. *[OpenFileDialog in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/1595/)* gives some examples of use.

Comment: would that not then mean the user has to open the files? really i just want them to save them.

Comment: The openfiledialog is just a way of selecting file names.  You get the filenames from the dialog when it closes using the `dialog.FileNames` property.  There is also a [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) that would serve the same purpose

Comment: sorry about this. So i get the user to open the openfilefialogue and they select the files they wish to save. then i get the file names using dialog.filenames How do i then approach saving those files to the requiredlocation?

Comment: @Rik I think Reniuz answer below is a good example of how to save the files.  If you are struggling with how to save files I suggest looking at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984409(VS.71).aspx) documentation